# MySQL: Concatenate different values as single value

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql db table I have projects with one to many relation with domain table like

**projects**

```
----------------
proId | domainId
----------------
  1        1
  1        2
  2        1
  3        3
```

**domain**

```
---------------------
domainId | domainName
---------------------
    1        Web
    2        Mobile
    3        iPhone
```

I query

```
SELECT p.*, d.* FROM projects p LEFT JOIN domain d ON p.domainId = d.domainId
```

which results

**result**

```
-----------------------------
proId | domainId | domainName
-----------------------------
  1       1          Web
  1       2          Mobile
  2       1          Web
  3       3          iPhone
```

but is it possible to show all domains as single value with concatenation some thing like

```
-----------------------------
proId | domainId | domainName
-----------------------------
  1       1, 2    Web, Mobile
  2       1       Web
  3       3       iPhone
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you are looking for **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** function.

```
SELECT  a.proID,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.domainID) domainId,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.domainName) domainName
FROM    projects a
        LEFT JOIN domain b
            ON a.domainID = b.domainID
GROUP BY a.proID
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5844/1)

Comment: (1) That should be a `LEFT JOIN`, not an `INNER JOIN`. (2) You should probably have `ORDER BY b.domainID` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`. (3) Why change the OP's mnemonic `p` and `d` to the meaningless `a` and `b`? And why change `domainId` to `domainID`? (4) The `DISTINCT`s seem unnecessary, and may add a performance penalty. (5) `GROUP_CONCAT` is documented at [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: @ruakh does changing the `alias` affects the answer? It's because I used to start my aliases at `a`. is mysql case sensitive?

Comment: Neither `p`/`d`-vs.-`a`/`b` nor `domainId`-vs.`domainID` will affect the results of the query; but they're both strange changes to make. Unless there's a problem with the OP's naming convention, why mess with it?

Comment: Thanks yes that should be LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

For quick question I just posted major points now as by help of friends it is solved & now i am posting complete DB Schema & Query.

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE projects
    (`projectId` int, `projectName` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO projects
    (`projectId`, `projectName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'P1'),
    (2, 'P2'),
    (3, 'P3')
;

CREATE TABLE domain
    (`domainId` int, `domainName` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO domain
    (`domainId`, `domainName`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Web'),
    (2, 'Mobile'),
    (3, 'iPhone')
;

CREATE TABLE prodomain
    (`domainId` int, `projectId` int)
;

INSERT INTO prodomain
    (`domainId`, `projectId`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 1),
    (3, 2),
        (2, 3)
;
```

**Query**

```
    SELECT p.projectId as proId, projectName, d.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(d.domainId separator ', ') as all_domains_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(d.domainName separator ', ') as all_domains_name 
FROM projects p 
    LEFT JOIN projectdomains pd ON p.projectId = pd.projectId
    LEFT JOIN domains d ON d.domainId = pd.domainId
    GROUP BY p.projectId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.proId, 
    group_concat(d.domainId) as domainId, 
    group_concat(d.domainName) as domainName 
FROM 
    projects p 
    inner JOIN 
    domain d ON p.domainId = d.domainId
group by p.proId
order by p.proId
```